# Can't link app in Fabric to existing Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to migrate my Android app from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics. My app has an existing Firebase project set up for messaging and analytics. This Firebase project is not yet linked to Fabric.

I start in the Firebase console. When I select the Crashlytics option for my app, I'm asked if the app is already set up for Crashlytics, which it is.

[image]

When I confirm this, I'm then prompted to head over to Fabric and link the Crashlytics app to the Firebase project.

[image]

So I follow that link and head over to Fabric to start the migration process.
In Fabric, I'm prompted to drag or click to create a new Firebase project.

[image]

Regardless of whether I drag an app or click, I'm prompted to set up a new Firebase project. It does not allow me to enter the existing Firebase Project ID. If I try, by editing the Project ID field, it tells me that the ID is already taken.

[image]

How can I link my existing Firebase project here?

Comment: Do you see any of your Firebase projects listed below the image of "Drag a Fabric app here..."? If not, are you logged in with the same Google account as the one associated with your Firebase projects?

Comment: My main Fabric login is with a different Google account - a personal account which I use with several different organisations in Fabric. When I hit the migration flow in Fabric, I'm asked which Google account I want to use with Firebase, and I select the correct account for Firebase (specific to the particular organisation) at that point. The Firebase apps do not show up in Fabric after doing this. Do I need to create a separate Fabric login with this organisation-specific Google account?

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, you'll want to contact support(at)fabric(dot)io so that they can look into the specifics of your apps and Firebase projects. Sorry for the issue!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After contacting Fabric support, they helpfully pointed out that I need to be an owner of the Firebase project in order for the migration to work. After I became an owner, the Firebase project showed up in Fabric and the migration worked flawlessly.

Comment: how did you became an owner of the firebase project ?